# How can I get a value from MySQL using jQuery on Frontend

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am using jQuery UI on the front end. I want to get the values off MySQL database on my page on a mouseclick using AJAX.

How do I retrieve data from MySQL using jQuery and update my div with the new HTML without a page refresh?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a service tier, which can be something like a PHP or ASP.net page that gets the $.ajax request from jQuery and executes a query against MySQL backend, then it will recieve the result from the DB,translate it back to something understandable from javascript side, (such as JSON)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need a server side controller or script to do the actual MySQL query. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026397/part-1-jquery-mysql-jquery-html).

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery there's a very helpful $ajax function using which you can send Get/Post requests to any webpage and use the retrieved information (which can be HTML) in your page.

Just give $ajax a look and your problem is solved. Though I don't hail from the PHP worls so I can't give you the exact code. Google it.